# How to install Tex live in a different directory than default one?

Tags: linux, tex, tex-live

As I dont have sudo or root access, I want to install Tex live at a different location but `install-tl` doesn't have any option for this. Is there any other workaround?

Default Path is: `/usr/local/texlive/2014`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`install-tl` looks for some enviroment variables when executed.
`TEXLIVE_INSTALL_PREFIX` has a default value of `/usr/local/texlive` and `TEXLIVE_INSTALL_TEXDIR` of `/usr/local/texlive/2014`.

Try to change those variable for the directory that you want to install, like:

```
TEXLIVE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/your_user/texlive
TEXLIVE_INSTALL_TEXDIR=/home/your_user/texlive/2014
```

I never tried this, but it might work.

You can read [this](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) and [this](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/install-tl.html) for more information.

Comment: Worked for me too!

Comment: Yes, it works. To be more specific, after `perl install-tl` one should hit `D` and type in new directory there.

Comment: Alternatively `$ perl ./install-tl -texdir ~/.local/texlive/2022 --no-interaction` works. The option `-texdir` is described in the installer's documentation that can be seen with `perl ./install-tl --help` which requires the perl-doc package (in Ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

I did the following 3 steps

1. `./install-tl` > `Enter command: P`
2. `sed -i 's|/usr/local/|~/|g' texlive.profile`
   *Modifies generated `texlive.profile` to replace all occurances of `/usr/local/` with `~/`*
3. Run `./install-tl -profile texlive.profile`